# What the difference in using validation helpers and calling custom validation methods from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Rails allows you to write custom validation methods for Models. The validators are called when you want them to and perform the actions you define for them. These validators can be called with `validates_with CustomValidator` or `validates :attribute, custom_validator: true`, etc.

You can also call class methods of the model from the associated controller. What is the difference between using these helpers and calling a validator method on the object straight from the controller, like Model.custom_validator(params)?

Are these helpers there to keep the controller lean or is there a more fundamental reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These validators can be called with `validates_with CustomValidator` or `validates :attribute, custom_validator: true`

Wrong. Those are the ways to **define** validations, not call them. The validations are triggered automatically. Before each save, for example.

> Are these helpers there to keep the controller lean or is there a more fundamental reason?

Both, actually. Validation logic does not belong in controllers. It should either be done in models or, if you're that kind of person, in [form objects](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects). Controllers should care about parsing params, enforcing authentication, rendering correct view, etc. They should not even be aware of validations.

Comment: I agree with you on those being ways to define validations, I was wrong there. Would it be more correct to say that you can define the methods to be called on validation using these helpers?

Comment: So you define the validator separately as a class inheriting from a Validator class. Then these helpers pass the record/thing to be validated to the validator that it points to?

Comment: @RM3: if you use custom validator classes, yes, that is what happens. Also you can use custom validator methods. But most of the time you use built-in validations, for which you don't have to define anything.

Comment: Off topic question, what percentage of validators used in your projects are custom and what percentage are built into rails? Spasiba

Comment: @RM3: most of them are standard validations (90%+)